# Get code coverage report for all classes in Intellij

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I'm using Intellij IDEA to try to generate a code coverage report for a java project. I followed the instructions here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-coverage.html and configured my coverage to target a specific package. When I run my tests, I get a coverage report, but it only includes information on one class. Digging deeper, it looks like the report only includes information on classes with uncommitted changes.

How do I force intellij to generate a coverage report for ALL classes in a package, regardless of their commit status?

Comment: the best is probably to create a bug here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach a sample project to reproduce